# Optimizing the number of tasks per core in Azure Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, sparkr, spark-submit, azure-databricks

I'm using **Azure Databricks** to deploy some R code parallelized through several workers using **SparkR** and `gapplyCollect()`.

---

#### Project overview

- I have **10000+ similar data sources** generating a lot of transactional information to be analyzed on a daily basis;
- I have an **R function** that analyzes all the information of **1 data source at a time**, giving me some valuable insights about that specific data source;
- So, every day I need to **execute my R function 10000+ times** for analyzing all my data.

#### Code Logic

1. Read all the data (from a relational DB) as a `SparkDataframe`
2. `groupBy()` the `SparkDataframe` based on my data source column *(data is evenly distributed by the data source column)*
3. Use `gapplyCollect()` on the `GroupedData` result of last step, for applying my R function on each data partition.

   - The result of each execution is a small R `DataFrame` with a few rows (*dim == (5,5)*).
   - All of the results are joined by `gapplyCollect()` execution, generating a small R `DataFrame` *(<100k numerical rows)* that consolidates all the results.
4. Persist the result on my **DBFS**.

---

## My issue

In my dev environment I'm making some experimentation parallelizing the analysis of 250 data sources, and I'm using 4 small workers for that *(VM type: Standard_F4s)*.

`gapplyCollect()` is sending my R function to the workers, but... Is it possible to customize the maximum number of active tasks to be executed per worker? As a default, I'm seeing that **Databricks** is allowing 5 Active Tasks per worker.

[image: Azure Databricks maximum tasks per worker]

- For example: How can I allow 8 tasks to be executed in parallel on each worker? Is [`spark-submit`](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-submit.html) suitable for this task?

I've never used `spark-submit` and I didn't find a good documentation for using it on **Azure Databricks**.

- I'll bring this code to production using a daily scheduled job. In the job, can I use for example the `spark-submit` feature to change the `--executor-cores` option?
- If yes, how do I guarantee that I'm installing the `forecast` CRAN Library in all my job driver + workers, since **Azure Databricks** don't allow me to define libraries in the GUI when using the `spark-submit`?

Comment: each core can only run 1 task at a time, have you tried increasing the number of cores of each executor?

Comment: For such a workload you are going to need bigger instance and configure dynamic resource allocation https://databricks.com/session/dynamic-resource-allocation-do-more-with-your-cluster

Comment: @MinhThai Yes I've tried and it increases the number of active tasks and it speeds up the whole processing time. But what I was trying to optimize now is the ratio between tasks/core, test if changing this ratio down or up, then I can further improve execution time.

Comment: @sramalingam24 As far as I understand dynamic resource allocation wouldn't be a good option for this usage case, since I want to create a cluster on demand, execute all my 10000+ computations and then terminate the cluster. This cluster will be created and terminated automatically based on a scheduled pipeline. I don't have a variable load job and I won't use a shared cluster.

Answer (score 1):

I've accessed the Databricks' Managed Resource Group with all the internally created resources *(like VMs, Disks & Network Interfaces)*.

There I've checked the CPU consumption metrics for each one of my workers. Here's the result for a **2x Worker** cluster:

[image: Databricks workers CPU usage metrics]

Here's the same chart capturing the moment when the tasks finally ended:

[image: Databricks workers CPU usage metrics 2]

Based on these metrics we can see that:

- Average CPU usage is 85~87%
- Max CPU usage is 92~96%
- Min CPU usage is 70~80%

These metrics are ok for my use case... **But if anyone have any clues about how to use `spark-submit` with Databricks, please feel free to share a new answer here.**